# Lines and secondary y-axis are not displayed in plotly barplot with overlying line chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have the dataframe created below with which I want to create a barplot with an overlapping line chart. The first y axis will include the variable `Freq` while the secondary will include the variable `rollmean`. But for some reason the lines and the secondary y-axis are not displayed.

**the dataframe**

```
date<-c(as.Date("2020-09-15", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-14", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-13", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-12", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-15", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-14", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-13", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-12", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-16", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-17", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-18", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-19", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-20", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-21", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-22", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-23", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-24", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-25", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-26", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-27", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-28", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-29", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-30", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-10-01", "%Y-%m-%d"))
value<-c(5,6,7,8,-3,-5,6,8,5,6,7,8,-3,-5,6,8,5,6,7,8,-3,-5,6,8)
df<-data.frame(date,value)
df2<-data.frame(table(df$date))


library(data.table)

adaptiveparam2 <- c(1:6, rep(7, nrow(df2)-6))
df2$rollmean <- frollmean(df2$Freq, n=adaptiveparam2, adaptive = T)
```

**and the plot code**

```
library(hrbrthemes)

g<-ggplot(df2, aes(x=Var1)) +
  
  geom_bar( aes(y=Freq), stat="identity", size=.1, fill="steelblue", color="black", alpha=.4) + 
  geom_line( aes(y=rollmean), size=2, color="red") +
  
  scale_y_continuous(
    
    # Features of the first axis
    name = "Temperature (Celsius °)",
    
    # Add a second axis and specify its features
    sec.axis = sec_axis( ~.,name="Price ($)")
  ) + 
  
  theme_ipsum() +
  
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "steelblue", size=13),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red", size=13)
  ) +
  
  ggtitle("Temperature down, price up")

ggplotly(g)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `group = 1` inside the `aes` of `geom_line`, but this leaves the problem of overlapping x axis date labels. I think the optimum solution here is to convert the dates to an actual date class:

```r
ggplot(within(df2, Var1 <- as.Date(Var1)), aes(x=Var1)) +
  geom_bar( aes(y=Freq), stat="identity", size=.1, 
            fill="steelblue", color="black", alpha=.4) + 
  geom_line( aes(y=rollmean), size=2, color="red") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Temperature (Celsius °)",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis( ~.,name="Price ($)")) +   
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(color = "steelblue", size=13),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red", size=13)) +
  ggtitle("Temperature down, price up")
```

[image]

If you need it to work in plotly, you will have to include the secondary axis in plotly itself:

```r
g <- ggplot(within(df2, Var1 <- as.Date(Var1)), aes(x=Var1)) +
  geom_bar( aes(y=Freq), stat="identity", size=.1, 
            fill="steelblue", color="black", alpha=.4) +
  geom_line( aes(y=rollmean), size=2, color="red") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Temperature (Celsius °)") +   
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(color = "steelblue", size=13),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red", size=13)) +
  ggtitle("Temperature down, price up")

ggplotly(g) %>%
    add_lines(x= ~Var1, y=  ~rollmean, colors = ~rollmean, yaxis="y2", 
            data=df2, showlegend=FALSE, inherit=TRUE)  %>%
  layout(yaxis2 = list(
  tickfont = list(size=11.7),
  titlefont=list(size=14.6, col = "red"),
  overlaying = "y",
  nticks = 5,
  side = "right",
  title = "Price ($)"
))
```

[image]

Comment: are u sure it creates a line now? I cannot see it. the 'rollmean' variable seems not to be used

Comment: @firmo23 sorry - I should have left the `geom_line` call in - now updated.